# Where to find documentation of arbitrary ROS2 package?

Tags: api, documentation, ros2

As the title states: where can I find documentation and API of standard packages, that are included with a certain ROS2 release (e.g. message_filters for foxy)?

I cannot find it in the official ROS2 documentation https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/index.html and while the repository contains a .dox file, I cannot find the output generated from it.

Answer (score 0):

you best look in the github repo for that like here[Github repo](https://github.com/intel/ros2_message_filters).

since they have changed the tutorials page you can only use a search machine to find that particular one (ros2 filter messages)

Comment: I found that repository earlier, but to me it appears not to reflect the latest version of the module. The official version is hosted here: https://github.com/ros2/message_filters - which in turn does not contain an easily readable documentation.

Comment: that is true. Unfortunately the try to stick as far as possible to the old stuf. So please don't get confused. As long you don't find a ros2 documentation the old one is valid. Still it can be that not everything is already there in ROS 2. sorry there are no better news